# let $0<x<y$ and $x,y$ be irrational number . now what ? Does it exist ? if yes How is that?

Tags: number-theory

in $x^y=y^x$ I know that all rational solutions are of the form :

$$\begin{align*}x &= (1+1/u)^u \\ y &= (1+1/u)^{u+1}\end{align*} \ \ u =1 ,2 , ...$$

---

let $0<x<y$ and $x,y$ be  irrational number . now what ? Does it exist ? 
if yes How is that ? i want all solutions in irrational number(generaly real number) .

Comment: The expressions you gave are a solution of the equation even if $u$ is irrational.

Comment: @ProfessorVector . all solution ?

Comment: If you need *all* solutions (in real numbers, complex numbers,...?), write so *in your question*, please!

Comment: @ProfessorVector I updated

Comment: @ProfessorVector Can you find all the solution?

Answer (score 2):

From your equation,$$x^y=y^x,$$ by dividing both sides by $x^x$ you'll arrive at
$$\frac{x^y}{x^x}=x^{y-x}=x^{x(y/x-1)}=\frac{y^x}{x^x}=\left(\frac{y}x\right)^x.$$ Under your assumption $x>0$, raising both sides to power $1/x$ gives
$$x^{y/x-1}=\frac{y}x.$$ You assume $y>x$, so you have
$$\frac{y}x=1+\dfrac1u\tag1$$ with some $u>0$, and you obtain
$$x^{1/u}=1+\frac1u.$$ Raising both sides to power $u$ implies
$$x=\left(1+\frac1u\right)^u\tag2.$$ Combining (1) and (2) you get
$$y=\left(1+\frac1u\right)^{u+1}\tag3.$$ So you see that (2) and (3) with some real $u>0$ give all real solutions $0<x<y$ of your equation, indeed.

Comment: but Not all solution .

Comment: @Fricul38 That gives all solutions with $0<x<y$, if you can follow the reasoning (if you see a gap, there, be more specific where it is, please). Of course, the original equation  has more solutions, $x=y>0$ will do, too.

Comment: why : $x^{x(y/x-1)}=(y/x)^x$